# Render error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'username)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

as soon as I try to get the user.username displayed in the  element I get a Render error: at line {user.username} stating that it cannot read properties of null

```
function Profile() {
  
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  
  const {userToken, signOut} = React.useContext(AuthContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadUser() {
      const response = await fetch('http://10.0.2.2:3000/me', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      });
      if (!response.ok) {
        setError('Error loading profile');
      }

      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
      setUser(data);
      setLoading(false);
    }
    loadUser();
  }, [userToken]);

  return (
    <Container>
      <Text>{user.username}</Text>
      <Text>{user.email}</Text>
      <TochableOpacity onPress={() => signOut()}>
        <ButtonText>LOGOUT</ButtonText>
      </TochableOpacity>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default Profile;
```

Answer (score 0):

When your component renders, you don't have a `user` yet. The request is async, so you should expect an empty user in your template. If you only want to show the `<Container>` if there is a user, try returning `null` until you have it.

```
if (!user) {
  return null;
}

return (
    <Container>
      ...
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Or alternatively, use optional chaining, something like this:

```
<Text>{user?.username}</Text>
<Text>{user?.email}</Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

You initialize it with `null`

```
const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
```

and then do `user.username` and `user.email`, so naturally it errors.

The `useEffect` runs after the render, and the `loadUser` is async, so until that returns it will remain null.

---

Either show something else while `loading` is `true` or initialize it to `{}` so that it does not crash.

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({});
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting my own solution that works!!! and THanks to Gabriele Petrioli and maten for trying to help out so quickly!
The solution was that I copy pasted from another component and I hadn't switch to 'GET' method instead of 'POST' and the token: userToken wasn't set in the header.

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function loadUser() {
      const response = await fetch('http://10.0.2.2:3000/me', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          token: userToken,
```